# 10+ razor page code behind get dbcontexts via dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

I develop an `C# ASP.NET Core MVC` app with a lot of `razor pages`.
Most of my razor pages use **logging**, **sending e-mails** and use **multiple dbcontextes**.

A lot of class looks like this:

```
class A : PageModel
{
        private readonly ADbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
        private readonly ILogger<MyModel> _logger;

        public UpdateModel(ADbContext context,
                            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                            IEmailSender emailSender,
                            ILogger<MyModel> logger)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _logger = logger;
        }
}
```

I have 10+ pages like this.
When I create a page, I have to add these fields. So for a lot of times.

What would be the ideal approach to get rid of lot of field declarations? A `base class` that inherits every page model that I develop? But this base class would be a really general base class with logging, with Email and with contextes that really not similarly fit to each other.
Is it a good architectural choice to declare these fields every time I declare a class that uses them?

Comment: There is a possibility of applying a pattern you are not seeing. Can you describe the responsibility of these pages? Additionally you could offset this code to an interactor which will do a better job of describing the organizing tasks. Further you can take a look at MediatR library. You could potentially move the logger to a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes, this is just what you do. Your dependencies are being injected, which means you need ivars to hold them and a constructor to accept them. It can feel and seem repetitive, but it's actually a good thing. It makes your class glanceable: you can quickly see what dependencies the class has at a glance.

You can create a base class if you like. However, you should be careful to only include things in your based class that are truly applicable to every derivation. The danger is in adding dependencies that aren't actually needed in all cases, and then now you have a bunch of pages loading dependencies they don't need and don't utilize.

You can also use abstractions to some extent here. For example, if each page depends on a context, but it might be different contexts in different scenarios, you can make the ivar typed as `DbContext`, instead of your concrete context type, and then you can set it to any valid derivation of `DbContext`. The same goes for your logger. You'd actually want to inject `ILogger<MyPageModel>`, but you can make the ivar on the base class just `ILogger`, which will then accept any logger.

Still, when you start to do this, you make it harder to suss out the dependencies of your classes, so it's a give and take. Personally, I'd only use a base class for shared logic, if any exists. If the only purpose of the base class is to define a particular set of dependencies, it's not worth having.

Answer (score 0):

could it be a good occasion to use Filters instead ?  Your filter dependencies could be injected via DI ?

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters

You can also simplify some cases of DI by injecting directly at function level where the service is required instead of inject at constructor level by adding '[FromService]' juste above the parameter :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult OnGetDoSomething([FromServices] IEmailSender emailService)
    {
        // Do something
    }
```

This way, you won't have to instanciate thoses services if the aren't required.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
class A : BasePage {
    public UpdateModel(IServiceProvider provider) : base(provider) {

        // here you can access the base properties

    }
}

class BasePage : PageModel {
    public ADbContext _context { get; set; }
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager; { get; set; }
    public IEmailSender _emailSender; { get; set; }
    public ILogger<MyModel> _logger; { get; set; }

    public UpdateModel(IServiceProvider provider) : base(provider) {
        Context = (ADbContext)provider.GetRequiredService(typeof(ADbContext));
        UserManager = (UserManager)provider.GetRequiredService(typeof(UserManager));
        EmailSender = (IEmailSender)provider.GetRequiredService(typeof(IEmailSender));
        Logger = (ILogger)provider.GetRequiredService(typeof(ILogger));
    }
}
```